# Convert received data in C++

Tags: python, c++, variables, data-conversion

I'm Working with Arduino (C++) and Raspberry Pi (Pyhon) with a RF module.

I've some doubts with the conversion of the data. I'm sending this data from Arduino:

```
unsigned long numbers = {12345678};
```

and Raspberry receive: `12345678`

The library I'm using has a `ackPayload` function, so I can send data back like this:

```
akpl_buf = [c,1,2,3]
```

The `c` variable is just an incremental number.

Now, in the Arduino I receive this:

```
Received Ack:235802126
```

I use an `static uint32_t` variable to receive the answer to the raspberry and I printed it like this (In Arduino C++): `printf("Received Ack:%lu\n\r",message_count);`

The question is, how can I convert the received data? it should be like: `12,1,2,3` or `12123`

Plus: what type of data is currently printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and ask some people, I knew that the RF library returned the data in bytes so `Received Ack:235802126` is the conversion from byte to unsigned long

so what I had to do was assign that data to a char array, and after that print it

```
char data[20];

importData(&data);
data[size+1] = '\0';

print data;
```

something like that.